# matplotlib plot_date default to 0 for missing dates in Xs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that defines the time at which events happen. It does not include timestamps for non-events. I want a 0-1 graph showing 0 on days no event occurred and 1 on days at least 1 event occurred.

My matplotlib code:

```
    #xs = [a bunch of datetimes]
    #ys = [1,1,.....,1] #of length Xs

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(xs, ys, '-')

    # format the ticks
    months = MonthLocator()
    days = DayLocator()

    yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%m-%d')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    ax.grid(True)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

This just shows a flat line of `y=1` from the first date in xs to the last date in xs. Probably it is interpolating for the time when there is no Xs values, which are all 1s.

How can I get `plot_date` to have a y value of 0 for all dates not in xs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Pandas to solve this problem. However, I still feel that turning interpolation off should be a supported feature in `plot_date`.

```
    sorted_xs = sorted(xs)

    #form a pandas date index
    #http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html
    freq = {}
    for i in pandas.date_range(start=sorted_xs[0], end=sorted_xs[-1], freq='D', normalize = True):
        freq[i] = 0

    for i in xs:
        freq[i] += 1

    plot_ys = []
    for key, value in sorted(freq.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True):
        plot_xs.append(key)
        plot_ys.append(value)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot_date(plot_xs, plot_ys, '-')

    yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%m-%d')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(DayLocator())
    ax.autoscale_view()

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an explicit list of all the dates and whether they have an event:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, MonthLocator

xs = map(lambda x:dt.date(x[0],x[1],x[2]),
         [(2015, 8, 12), (2015, 8, 14), (2015, 8, 16), (2015, 8, 16)])
ys = [1,2,1,1]
dates = [min(xs) + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((max(xs) - min(xs)).days+1)]
marks = [x in xs for x in dates]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, marks, 'o-')
```

If your ys list sometimes has 0-values, you'll need to handle that. Also, if you do a lot of things like this, look into the pandas library.

[image]

Comment: just as a note, `marks = [x in xs for x in dates]` is O(DX) where D is len dates and X is len xs. You can use a dictionary to make this faster in O(D+X) as per in my solution.